DRY for kustomize transformers, how can I replace parts of their configuration?
For a recent kustomization project, I've noticed lots of redundancy in my transformers.
Consider the follwing kustomization.yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- ../../base

configMapGenerator:
- literals:
  - CUSTOMER=customerx
  name: settings

transformers:
- transform-customer.yaml

which references the following transform-customer.yaml:
---
apiVersion: builtin
kind: PrefixTransformer
metadata:
  name: customer-prefix
prefix: customerx-
fieldSpecs:
  - path: metadata/name
---
apiVersion: builtin
kind: LabelTransformer
metadata:
  name: customer-label
labels:
  customer: customerx
fieldSpecs:
  - path: metadata/labels

Even for this small example, you can see that the customer name customerx is referenced 3 times, once in the ConfigMap and then again for each transformer.
Is there any way of transforming the transformers, so I can inject the customer name from the ConfigMap (note that the 1st transformer needs a trailing - for the prefix property)?
As variables are deprecated I took a look at the ReplacementTransformer (corresponding to the replacements YAML key), but neither could it just replace a part of the target property, nor could I get it to transform my transformers, only regular Kubernetes resources.
Do you have any idea how I can get rid of the redundancy? Please note that this is only a minimal example, there are more values and transformations that need to be handled in the same way.
